# How to implement methods found in the Mac Developer Library

Tags: objective-c

I'm a totally new to Objective C programming and just need to check how would I implement something I find on the Mac Developer Library.
For example I found this code in the Mac Developer Library:

```
- (BOOL)containsObject:(id)anObject
```

Are the steps I need to implement this method?

1. in the .h file add

   `-(BOOL)containsObject:(id)anObject;`

then in the .m file implement it like this;

```
- (BOOL)containsObject:(id)anObject
{
   //What do I place here to search my array with the objects?
   return YES;
}
```

Can someone help me with an example how I would search an array of numbers and use this method?

This is my array:

```
NSArray *first;

first = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:1,2,3,4,5, nil];
```

Comment: The numbers you see there ("1, 2, 3, 4, 5") are integers, which are raw C types and not Objective-C objects, so you can't store them in a NSArray.  You can store NSNumber objects in an array though.

Comment: Oh ok.  How would I search to see if an array contains a number like:  int first[9] = { 0,4,3,7,6,8,4,5,6} ;

Comment: I've tried making this question clearer. Is this better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean "implement" - as in write your own version - or "use"? You seem to start with the former and end with the latter...

How do you use it? Well taking your example, corrected:

```
NSArray *first = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@1, @2, @3, @4,@ 5, nil];
```

The `@1` etc. is a shorthand to create an `NSNumber` *object* - you can only put object references and not primitive values into an `NSArray`. The shorthand effectively expands to `[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]` etc.

Now to use `containsObject:`:

```
BOOL containsTheAnswerToEverything = [first containsObject:@42];
```

This will set the `BOOL` variable to `YES` if the array contains an `NSNumber` representing 42, and `NO` otherwise.

How do you implement it? You examine each element of your array in a loop comparing each to the object you are looking for, same algorithm you would use in C (which it seems you know).

If you are asking how to define a class, then you should read up on Objective-C, but your point 2 is the correct outline.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

In respect to the first question, you can do just that. An example to give you a better visual understanding would be this:

```
YourClassName.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface YourClassName : Subclass  //replace subclass with something like NSObject or whatever you need
{

}

- (BOOL)containsObject:(id)anObject;

@end
```

and...

```
YourClassName.m

#import "YourClassName.h"

@implementation YourClassName

- (BOOL)containsObject:(id)anObject
{
    //Insert function body here
}

@end
```

As for your second question, I am not really very familiar with using NSArray or loading it using that strange function. My advice would be using (NSArray)anObject instead of (id)anObject as you can load the array directly into your function and create your search parameters there. I'm not sure exactly what object you are looking for in terms of containsObject. Are you seeing if it contains the number? If the value contains the array? specify it a bit and I may be able to dig up a better answer for you

**EDIT:**

It occurred to me that you are probably just looking for the number inside of the array seeing as you are newer to Objective-C. To accomplish what you want you have a couple options. Both require the change of your function. The first would be just changing the function to this:

```
- (BOOL)containsObject:(int)object fromArray:(int*)array length:(int)length;
```

In YourClassName.h. Now you can always change your parameters to different data types but this will work for your integers. You can also do this without the length parameter but I figure it saves us some code (personal preference). And in the .m file:

```
- (BOOL)containsObject;(int)object fromArray:(int*)array length:(int)length
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= length; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] == object)
        {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

second would be just without the length option and a bit more code